# Is it ok to improve the negative vote question?

Tags: discussion

I just tried to improve this [question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/89916/changing-the-logic-for-an-exposed-taxonomy-select-in-a-view/) with formatting, grammar and highlighted the points with blockquote, purposely I done, because the question got 1 negative vote with bounty enabled and don't have enough attention . Is it ok to improve the negative vote question, suppose if it even don't have any grammatical mistake ?

**Why I'm asking this question ?**

User of the question, raised a [question](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2712/unecessary-edits-to-my-question) on meta and one of his comment discouraged me lot

> What's wrong with the question? I would suggest @Bala that you don't
>   try to make grammatical changes and changes of tone if you don't speak
>   fluent English.

I raised a flag as rude or offensive, but declined by the mod, I don't know whenever I see this comment I'm struggling, because that question is now active in Community Bulletin.

Comment: *"...highlighted the points with blockquote"*?

Comment: @JonW Yes I done it to make the points more visible

Comment: @Bala, I'm afraid your edit was not seen as an improvement, and I can understand why. If anything, it was more like a regression (and writing `Fixed grammer` in the comment did not help things).

Comment: Please don't "use" such tools to simply highlight sections @Bala. Blockquote are for quotes. Code formatting is for code. Don't use it for other means.

Comment: @Bart Ok I will not use it anymore, for highlight purpose's

Comment: FYI: [-our, -or](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_and_British_English_spelling_differences#-our.2C_-or) and [behaviour](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/behaviour)

Comment: FWIW, I occasionally use block quotes to improve the look of my questions (and others). There is a time and a place for it and I don't think Bala's usage of it in this edit was problematic. I think it was the grammatical issues that most prompted the roll-back.

Comment: Btw, with regards to the question in your title: Yes, edits are certainly welcome. Improvements are great. And thank you for being willing to contribute in such a positive manner. Just make sure that your edits are correct and don't introduce new problems. And learn from mistakes. Good luck. ;)

Comment: @Bart thanks for the encouragement.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I suspect the "fluent English" comments were due to the following changes:

> **Original**
> What I would now like to do is extend the behaviour of the filter so that the following happens:
>
> **Your change**
> What I would like to do is, extend the behavior of the filter like the following

This is not a grammatical improvement. If anything, it is now more erroneous due to the misplaced comma.

> **Original**
> Or will I need to use a hook - if so, which hook and any ideas about how I might approach it?
>
> **Your change**
> Or will I need to use a hook - if so, which hook I have to use?, any ideas how I might approach it?

Again, this is now more grammatically incorrect and doesn't read like native English.

Comment: thanks for clarifying, this is enough for me.

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing wrong with improving a negative question through editing. It should even be encouraged. Although some questions are not really worth it, in some cases a little formating, spellchecking and clarification based on comments from the asker can often rescue a downvoted question.

But an edit should always be an improvement. When people feel that your edit is not really adding value or even makes the question worse, a negative feedback is to be expected.